# Return error message if password or user email wrong in flutter login form

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

Hy Guys I have connected flutter to my firebase project and used AUTH feature in Firebase but what I would do is to show an error message when a wrong password or Email user is wrong.
this is my code:

```
Widget submitButton (){
    return Container(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 220,
        height: 40,
        child: MaterialButton(
          elevation: 5,
          onPressed: () async {
            setState(() {
              showProgress = true;
            });

            try {
              final newUser = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
              print(newUser.toString());
              if (newUser != null) {
                Navigator.push(context, PageTransition(
                  type: PageTransitionType.fade,
                  child: WelcomeScreen(),
                ));
                setState(() {
                  showProgress = false;
                });

              }
            } catch (e) {}
          },
          child: Text('Accedi',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
          color: Colors.white,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black12,width: 1)),
        ),

      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Try using a Form() with TextFormField()

Comment: could you be more specific please?

Comment: Check out the answer I submitted, hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to catch the error, you can do that by using `catchError()`:

```
final newUser = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
    .catchError((err) {
          showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text("Error"),
              content: Text(err.message),
              actions: [
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text("Ok"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                )
              ],
            );
          });
    });
```

Then the `showDialog` will have `err.message` which will contain the error received from Firebase Authentication.

Comment: Hello thanks and how to empty the fields once user clicks on OK and return back to the prompt?

Comment: You need to use a TextFormField for that and then do `myController.text = "";`. Check the cookbook its very good https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/retrieve-input

Comment: I see that will show the data into the alertDialog. what I want is once I click to try again the go back to the form I want cleaning the login form fields

Comment: when u are clicking ok, the alertdialog is poping then all you have to do is empty the fields, check the link i added in the comments

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1.Use an alert dialog

```dart
  void _showAlertDialog(String message) async {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text(message),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Ok'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

[full example](https://codepen.io/pegasisforever/pen/xxZaaqX)

[image]

2. Use `errorText` property in `InputDecoration`

```dart
TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        errorText: this.errorText,
    ),
)
```

[full example](https://codepen.io/pegasisforever/pen/bGExxRb)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Form() with TextFormField()

Something like this:

```
Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              key: ValueKey('email'),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty || !value.contains('@'))
                  return 'Please enter a valid Email address';
                return null;
              },
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email address'),
              onSaved: (value) {
                _userEmail = value;
              },
            ),
```

It's just a dummy, but as you see there's some validation code in the validator attribute.

So what validator does is, if you return null everything is well and good, but if something is wrong, just return the String and it'll be shown below the text form field as an error message.

And to validate you can call a method like this to activate the method while form submission

```
void _trySubmit() {
final bool isValid = _formKey.currentState.validate();
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

if (isValid) {
  _formKey.currentState.save();
  widget.submitFn(
    _userEmail.trim(),
    _userName.trim(),
    _userPassword.trim(),
    _isLogin,
    context,
  );
}}
```

The method for getting isValid will invoke validation function of all TextFormFields, if all of them are okay, it'll return true else it'll return false.

All the _name are used to store the values in state variables using the onSaved attribute.

Let me know if you have anymore doubts.

Hope this helps✌